# How do I generate a script with an inverse action

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort

I have an interactive script which sorts and processes a variety of filetypes from an unsorted folder into newly created directories.

I was wondering how I could write a small script or modify the existing script that so that I could unwind / undo the executed script and its sorting process back to the folders (pre sort) state if need be.

What is the leanest possible way of achieving this.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
        mkdir -p foldermisc 
        if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
        fi
    for i in folder*/; do
        ls -S "$i" > "${i}filelist" 
        cat "${i}filelist" >> ~/desktop/summary.txt
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a function that you could call after the (successful) `mv` commands, giving it the same parameters as you did for `mv`, and the function will echo out corresponding commands that should put the files back where they were. You could alternatively redirect these commands to a backout file; they are also commented out, just as a safety precaution.

```
function mvbackout {
  declare -a files
  for f
  do
    files+=("$f")
  done
  # remove the last parameter (the destination)
  unset files[$(( $# - 1 ))]
  dest=$f
  printf "# cd -- %s\n" "$PWD"
  for f in "${files[@]}"
  do
    printf "# mv -- '%s' '%s'\n" "${dest}/$(basename "$f")" "$f"
  done
}
```

The function (can't) recover from data-loss scenarios (where the initial mv command clobbered a file by accident; or a file was later moved or removed), but for the main idea, it should work.

**Important caveat**

Because re-quoting shell commands back to the shell is tricky, I've surrounded the filenames with single quotes, which means that copy/pasting the resulting command will not work *if* any of the filenames in that command contains single quotes.

Here's a sample run:

```
$ mkdir dest
$ touch a b
$ mkdir -p subdir1/subdir2/subdir3 mkdir fun\'d\'ir fun\'d\'ir/fun\"d\"ir
$ touch subdir1/c subdir1/subdir2/d subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/e 
$ mv a b subdir1/c subdir1/subdir2/d subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/e dest
$ mvbackout a b subdir1/c subdir1/subdir2/d subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/e dest
# cd -- /home/schaller/tmp/dir
# mv -- 'dest/a' 'a'
# mv -- 'dest/b' 'b'
# mv -- 'dest/c' 'subdir1/c'
# mv -- 'dest/d' 'subdir1/subdir2/d'
# mv -- 'dest/e' 'subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/e'
```

For your script, you could add another line after each `mv`, like so:

```
...
mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
mvbackout unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
... 
if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
then
   mvbackout unsorted/* "foldermisc" 
   echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
fi
```

Comment: appreciated Jeff

Comment: That function you wrote. Is that to be put in a new txt file and run separate? and# remove the last parameter (the destination). What do you mean. Have I to delete that line or put in a path

Comment: (1) it just has to be sourced in before you run your code; so it could be part of the same script or elsewhere. (2) that is a comment indicating that we're removing the original destination as a candidate for moving back to its original location.